# Why was Yui happy at the end?

Tags: speed-grapher

When Suitengu was explaining to Kamiya how he had already found his sister and she had been with him all this time (in the form of a charred bone fragment left from her ashes), it's shown that Suitengu found out that Yui has been sold as a prostitute and had become "broken" after years of abuse.

When she saw Suitengu, she started begging him for money and started to suck on his fingers. Suitengu wept a tear of blood which she swallowed before he hugged her. It's obvious that Suitengu used his power to put Yui to rest while they were hugging.

As Yui died, she was smiling. I am wondering, was she smiling because she realized the man hugging her was her older bother, or was she happy that she was freed from her life as a prostitute?

Comment: Why not both? Pain can be a great way to quickly induce sobriety, so after coming to her senses, Yui might have remembered her brother and understanding the damned awful situation, she, with relief, embraced her brother once more and let go of her life.

Answer (score 1):

I believe she was happy to be free from her life as a prostitute - When Suitengu enters, she treats him like another *client*, begging for money and initiating intimacy by sucking on his fingers.

Yui's life was a wreck and you can see in the scene that she has been reduced to a weak state of survival, having been badly treated for (presumably) years.
She was most likely glad to be free of the living hell she was in.

Her smile could be interpreted as a final recognition of her brother, but personally I doubt it - she is confused and dismissive of both the music box and when Suitengu hugs her, it's only moments before we see her hand drop that she smiles.